# Can Hibernate be used as the JPA provider in Google App Engine

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

Can [Hibernate 3.5.x](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.5.0-CR-2/) be used as the JPA provider instead of the default provider in the latest version of Google App Engine (1.3.2)

Comment: To answer that you need to define what datastore you want to persist to ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, Hibernate can't be used with Google App Engine. Please see [Will it play with App Engine](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava).

> You cannot currently use Hibernate
>   directly. The differences between the
>   App Engine datastore and SQL were too
>   great to get the standard Hibernate up
>   and running under App Engine. App
>   Engine does support JDO and JPA, so
>   you may be able to convert your
>   Hibernate code to use one of these ORM
>   interfaces.

Comment: Assuming we convert Hibernate code over to JPA 2, would it be possible to use Hibernate as the underlying JPA provider or would the GAE platform default this to default data nucleus provider

Comment: You need to use data nucleus.

Comment: Now it has Google Cloud SQL, can hibernate be used now?

Answer (score 9):

I appreciate that it's been some time since you asked, but things have changed recently; Google now offers a preview of a SQL interface. That means that any JDBC based solution should work (http://code.google.com/apis/sql/) - and that includes Hibernate.

Personally, I'll be cautious about using it until pricing is finalised, though.

Answer (score 5):

Yes,now, you can use hibernate with Google App Engine.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-gae/ (Mar 23, 2012)

Previously you cannnot use JDBC for queries, but now you can!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can !

Please read this [information](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/using_hibernate).

Comment: As of 2010 probably it was not possible.

Comment: the link is broken, that's why you need to put at least a summary of what should be done.